# What is responsible for caching the HTTP requests sent via AIR desktop application?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, air

When dealing with a flash application that will run in a browser, it's obvious that the browser will cache some of the HTTP requests. But when dealing with a desktop AIR application, what's caching them? Is it the OS, or the AIR container?

Reason I'm asking is that I've recently dealt with a really ugly and time consuming memory leak that happened only on MAC OSX (running on Windows was fine). The memory leak was solved with setting the headers of the HTTP requests I was making to include "Cache-control" = "no-store", "no-cache". But the fact that on one OS there's no memory leak, and on the other there is with the same AIR build is a probable indication of a bug somewhere. The question is where.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OS is caching the request, not the AIR platform (I knew that there were some requests to have the caching feature in AIR but for the moment it is not). Related to your memory leak I think that you should fill a bug on https://www.adobe.com/cfusion/mmform/index.cfm?name=wishform.

Comment: I was hoping I'd get an answer from you, seeing that you work for Adobe :) 
If the OS is caching them, why is the memory of my AIR application affected and not that of some internal OS process? 
Also, I'd be more than happy to fill a bug, but I'm not sure what the bug is. The fact that the requests are being cached on MAC, or that they are not being cached on Windows?

Comment: :) The bug is that you have a memory leak when the caching occurs. I would fill a bug for that (with all the details: code, AIR version, OS version etc.)